# jQuery jTable issue adding and editing when using nested JSON objects

Tags: jquery, object, null, nested, jquery-jtable

I have a jQuery jTable in my MVC application that is bound to a list of objects where one of the properties is a nested object. I'm able to get all values to display correctly, but the nested object is coming through to the server as null when trying to perform an add or an update.

For example, consider the following sample code:

**Base object:**

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Nested Address object:**

```
public class Address
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

**partial jTable definition:**

```
$('#UserList').jtable({
        title: "Users",
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Admin/LoadUsers',
            createAction: '/Admin/CreateUser',
            updateAction: '/Admin/UpdateUser',
            deleteAction: '/Admin/DeleteUser'
        },
        fields: {
            ID: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            AddressLine1: {
                title: 'Group',
                display: function(data){
                    return data.record.Address.AddressLine1;
                },
            }
        }
    });
```

**Controller Update Action:**

```
public JsonResult UpdateUser(User user)
{
   try
   {
       // Code to update user here...
       return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
   }
```

}

In the jTable the AddressLine1 will display just fine. However, when the Add or Update controller actions are run the User.Address object is coming through as null, so none of the values that were entered for the address are accessible to add or update. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have displayed the `AddressLine1` variable yourself by using the `display` attribute. When you create new record, `AddressLine1` will be another parameter like `ID` attribute in the form body. You can check the request body from the Developer Tools in chrome.

You can try to assign a function to the [createAction](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions#act-createAction) attribute with using [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and handle post request by yourself.

Example:

```js
createAction: function(postData, jtParams) {
  return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/create/api/url/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: prepareJSON(postData), // function to convert inputs to your JSON format
      success: function(data) {
        $dfd.resolve({
          "Result": "OK",
          "Records": data.description,
          "TotalRecordCount": 0
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("ERROR ....");
        $dfd.reject();
      }
    });
  });
}
```